# Conectividad de estudio de Android con postgresql

Tags: android-studio, postgresql

He seguido un tutorial para conectar PostgresSql con Android, pero aún así no he obtenido ninguna solución.

¿Cómo conecto Android Studio con PostgreSsql?

He escrito este código en mi `MainActitvity.java.`

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/user1";

//  Database credentials
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "root";

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Connection conn = null;
  Statement st = null;
 try{
    //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    //STEP 3: Open a connection
    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/","root","root");

    //STEP 4: Execute a query
    System.out.println("Creating statement...");
    st = conn.createStatement();
    String sql;
    sql = "SELECT  first, last FROM Employees";
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

    //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
    while(rs.next()){
        //Retrieve by column name
        String first = rs.getString("first");
        String last = rs.getString("last");

        //Display values
        System.out.print(", First: " + first);
        System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
    }
    //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
    rs.close();
    st.close();
    conn.close();
  }catch(SQLException se){
    //Handle errors for JDBC
    se.printStackTrace();
  }catch(Exception e){
    //Handle errors for Class.forName
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {
    //finally block used to close resources
    try{
        if(st!=null)
            st.close();
    }catch(SQLException se2){
    }// nothing we can do
    try{
        if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }//end finally try
  }
}
```

¿Es esto correcto o debo escribirlo en otra parte?

Comment: Ambos ejemplos son correctos algorítmicamente, pero la cuestión es que el driver no se ajusta o es incompatible, al menos los que estan disponibles. Pero si existe uno que funciona, pero no estoy seguro que sea oficial.

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco, a la hora de hacer algo así, te obliga a hacerlo de manera asíncrona, con lo cual deberías declararte una clase asíncrona donde hagas esa llamada.
Para ello puedes hacerlo así:

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/user1";

//  Database credentials
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "root";

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    //La llamada la ejecutamos así
    new HttpAsyncTask().execute();

    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //En esta parte del método es donde normalmente
            //creamos un cuadro de carga (ProgressDialog)
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            //En esta parte es donde realizamos la llamada. Se realiza de manera asíncrona
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement st = null;
              try{
                //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

                //STEP 3: Open a connection
                System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/","root","root");

                //STEP 4: Execute a query
                System.out.println("Creating statement...");
                st = conn.createStatement();
                String sql;
                sql = "SELECT  first, last FROM Employees";
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

                //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
                while(rs.next()){
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    String first = rs.getString("first");
                    String last = rs.getString("last");

                    //Display values
                    System.out.print(", First: " + first);
                    System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
                }
                //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
                rs.close();
                st.close();
                conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
                //Handle errors for JDBC
                se.printStackTrace();
            }catch(Exception e){
                //Handle errors for Class.forName
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                //finally block used to close resources
                try{
                    if(st!=null)
                        st.close();
                }catch(SQLException se2){
                }// nothing we can do
                try{
                    if(conn!=null)
                        conn.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException se){
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }//end finally try
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //En esta parte es donde tratamos el resultado devuelto por la llamada a la BBDD.
        }
    }
}
```

No he comprobado si la llamada que haces está bien o mal, pero te pongo esto para que veas donde tienes que poner tu código. Tienes que tener muy en cuenta que estás realizando una llamada asíncrona, con lo cual, tendrás que esperar a recibir los datos para trabajar con ellos, por eso tienes qeu hacerlo en el método onPostExecute.